# Chances for a cosine polynomial to be positive at a point

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, trigonometric-sums

Let $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ be distinct integers. Let $s_n(t)=\cos (k_1t)+\cdots+\cos (k_nt)$ be a trigonometric sum. Consider any interval $I\subset [-\pi,\pi)$ of length $\delta=\delta(n)$. Let $\,U$ be a uniform distribution in the interval $I$. I am interested in the quantity $\mathbb{P}(s_n(U)>0)$.

**Questions**: 1) (strong form) How large should $\delta(n)$ be so that we would have $\mathbb{P}(s_n(U)>0)\approx 1/2$?

2) (weak form) How large should $\delta$ be so that we would have $\mathbb{P}(s_n(U)>0)$ is bounded away from zero and one independently of $n$?

**Comment**: If $s_n$ is the Dirichlet kernel, that is, $k_i=i$, it is easy to see that we must have $\delta_n>>n^{-1}$. I would be content if one of the latter statements was true with $\delta(n)=1/\log (n)$.

Comment: Need to explain what is $f$.

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu Sorry, $f=s_n$, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe that even, say, $\delta_n=\pi/2$ works for large $n$?

Comment: Take a very fast growing sequence of $k_j>0$. Then $f=2s_n/\sqrt{n}$ has essentially standard normal distribution and $f(x)^2-2+n^{-1/2}f(2x)$ has all coefficients equal. However the probability that the standard normal random variable is between $-\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2$ is not $\frac 12$. This shows that we can skew the sign distribution somewhat at any scale. The question is how much...

Comment: @fedja Could you elaborate the statement  about similarity with  the normal distributions?

Comment: If you take several first moments, there are no resonances between frequences, so the moments are exactly the same as for independent random variables, which means that the distributions are close too.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Above you see a $12$-frame  animation  of the family of  trig polynomials

$$ P_k(t) =\cos t+\cos 2t+\cos 3t+\cos kt,\;\;\; k=4,\dotsc, 15. $$

I have included it to illustrate  the fact that  there seems to be another quantity relevant to your question, besides $n$, namely the degree $d=\max\{k_i;\;\;i=1.\dotsc, n\}$. In the above example $n=4$, but the degree varies from $4$ to $15$.

The next animation  may be more suggestive because you can  see large intervals where  the trig polynomials are negative. More precisely, below is a $10$-frame animation of the trig polynomials

$$P_k(t) =\cos 2t+\cos 3t+ \cos(4k+1)t, \;\;k=4,\dotsc, 13. $$

[image]

Comment: I can't prove it, but I expect "highly structured" examples to be the worst- the ones with lengthy arithmetic progressions ${k_1,\ldots k_n}$. And then degree plays no part. 

It may be that I am wrong, but as I said, I expect good behavior in sufficiently long intervals. Say $\delta=1/\log(n)$. For $n$ large, say $n=100$ and $\delta=1/\log(100)\approx 0.2$ I would expect many roots in the interval and thus many intervals many sing changes.

For $n=4$ one cannot see this effect as the length $\delta$ is comparable to the interval length where the sum of cosines changes sign.

Comment: After looking at many examples, your conjecture seems more and more plausible (and difficult). Fedja.s

Comment: Fedja's question is an excellent place to start. It suggests that maybe the $1/2$ in your question should be replaced by some universal number $c\in (0,1)$.

Comment: the latter is exactly the weaker form I asked (question 2).